# string to array in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, string, decode

I have string below in PHP/Javascript which is encoded. **How to make that string to array in PHP or javascript**?

```
data%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=Car&data%5B0%5D%5BPrice%5D=101&data%5B1%5D%5BName%5D=Laptop&data%5B1%5D%5BPrice%5D=201
```

I tried to decode string first. Then I tried to split("&") but That I result is different than I am looking.
**Javascript:**

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent(data%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=Car&data%5B0%5D%5BPrice%5D=101&data%5B1%5D%5BName%5D=Laptop&data%5B1%5D%5BPrice%5D=201)); 

// Result: data[0][Name]=Car&data[0][Price]=101&data[1][Name]=Laptop&data[1][Price]=201&data[2][Name]=Laptop&data[2][Price]=201
```

So I think split by "&" was not better Idea or Need to do more steps to make array.

In **PHP**, I tried to explod by "&" first and then tried to explode by "=" again but it gives me different result.

```
$mydata = "data%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=Car&data%5B0%5D%5BPrice%5D=101&data%5B1%5D%5BName%5D=Laptop&data%5B1%5D%5BPrice%5D=201";
                foreach ($mydata as $chunk) {
                    $param = explode("=", $chunk);
                    print("<pre>".print_r($param,true)."</pre>"); //prints first element


                    if ($param) {
                        printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n", urldecode($param[0]), 
                        urldecode($param[1]));

                       //First round:
                        Array
                        (
                         [0] => data%5B0%5D%5BName%5D
                         [1] => Car
                        )
                        //Second round:
                        Array
                        (
                        [0] => data%5B0%5D%5BPrice%5D
                        [1] => 101
                        )
                       $What_Should_Var_Name??  = urldecode($param[1]); 
                      //confuse to put variable name because [1] will be 
                      'Car' which represents "Name", but in second loop, same 
                      [1] will be '101' which will represent 'Price'. So I 
                      don't know how to store that here to make array.




                    }
                }
```

Comment: *"Then I tried to split("&") but That I result is different than I am looking."* - What was the result of that attempt and how does it differ from what you expect?  Splitting the URI-decoded string on "&" should indeed result in an array of strings, each of which is a key/value pair.  Splitting each on "=" should result in all of the key/value pairs being separated.  How does that differ from your goal?

Comment: Sounds like you need [`parse_str()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: Problem is how to store that value in foreach as one time [1] will represent "Name" while second Time, same [1] will be as "Price". So I can not put something Like that $Name = $param[1] because it will be $Price = $param[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I taste two questions here. Correct me if I am wrong.

1. How to decode the data to a usable array
2. How to use the array

## 1. How to decode the data to a usable array

I think you are looking for `urldecode()` and `parse_str()`.

```
$decodedString = urldecode('data%5B0%5D%5BName%5D=Car&data%5B0%5D%5BPrice%5D=101&data%5B1%5D%5BName%5D=Laptop&data%5B1%5D%5BPrice%5D=201');

// The above code will give you the following string in $decodedString:
data[0][Name]=Car&data[0][Price]=101&data[1][Name]=Laptop&data[1][Price]=20


parse_str($decodedString, $array);

// The above code will give you the following array in $array:
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(3) "Car"
      ["Price"]=>
      string(3) "101"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["Name"]=>
      string(6) "Laptop"
      ["Price"]=>
      string(2) "20"
    }
  }
}
```

## 2. How to use the array

If you would iterate over the array like this

```
foreach ($array['data'] as $data) {
    // So you can use $data['Name'] and $data['Price']

    // ITERATION 1:
    // $data will be ['name' => 'Car', 'Price' => '101']

    // ITERATION 2:
    // $data will be ['name' => 'Laptop', 'Price' => '20']
}
```

Comment: I could echo $data['Name']; and echo $data['Price']; It works good. Thanks.